# Compacting CMake unit test macros into one macro using conditional statement

Tags: foreach, cmake, ctest

I want to reduce the CMake macro calls in my code below and compact it into one CMake macro call to execute my operation using an if-else statement.

I need to run `ctest` (using CMake) by passing different height and width parameters.

Please consider this as some arithmetic operations.

In my case, depending on width, my height ranges will change like this:

```
  Width = 8 ,then height will be 8 16 24 
  Width = 16 ,then height will be 16 24 
  Width = 24 ,then height will be 24 32
```

So, is it possible to use some if-else statement in the CMake file to make a single call to `EXECUTE_OPERATION(${width_val} ${height_val} )`?

**My current CMake file looks like this:**

```
set(width 8) 
set(size 8 16 24 )

foreach(size_val ${size}
  foreach(width_val  ${width})

  EXECUTE_OPEARTION(${width_val} ${height_val} )

  endforeach(width_val)
endforeach(size_val)

---------------------------

set(width 16) 
set(height 16 24 )

foreach(height_val ${height}
  foreach(width_val  ${width})

  EXECUTE_OPEARTION(${width_val} ${height_val} )

  endforeach(width_val)
endforeach(size_val)

---------------------------

set(width 24) 
set(size 24 32 )

foreach(size_val ${size}
  foreach(width_val  ${width})

  EXECUTE_OPEARTION(${width_val} ${height_val} )

  endforeach(width_val)
endforeach(size_val)

---------------------------
```

**I tried to do this using the following, but it did not work:**

```
set(width 8 16 24 ) 
 if(width == 8)
  set(height 8 16 24 )
 elif(width == 16)
  set(height 16 24 )
 elif(width == 24)
  set(height 24 32)

foreach(height_val ${height}
  foreach(width_val  ${width})

  EXECUTE_OPEARTION(${width_val} ${height_val} )

  endforeach(width_val)
endforeach(size_val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-statement seems to have Python syntax. You should use `elseif` instead of `elif`. Also, the CMake if-statement [syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#condition-syntax) to test for equality is `EQUAL`, not `==`.

In addition, you need to move the if-statement block *within* the `foreach()` block in order for this to work. Try something like this:

```
# Define the width values to iterate through.
set(width 8 16 24)

# Iterate through each width value.
foreach(width_val ${width})
  # Set the height values, based on the current width value.
  if(${width_val} EQUAL 8)
    set(height 8 16 24)
  elseif(${width_val} EQUAL 16)
    set(height 16 24)
  elseif(${width_val} EQUAL 24)
    set(height 24 32)
  endif()

  # Loop through each height value.
  foreach(height_val ${height})
    message("Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: ${width_val}, Height: ${height_val}")
    EXECUTE_OPEARTION(${width_val} ${height_val})
  endforeach(height_val)
endforeach(width_val)
```

This prints the following, verifying the function is called with the correct arguments:

```
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 8, Height: 8
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 8, Height: 16
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 8, Height: 24
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 16, Height: 16
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 16, Height: 24
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 24, Height: 24
Calling EXECUTE_OPEARTION() with args: Width: 24, Height: 32
```

Comment: Thank you ..It helped me a lot !!

Comment: I want to ask one more query ..That  is it possible to use and (&&) or or (||) operator in if statement . As I have `width` 56 and 8 that will go with same `height` from 8 16 24 .

Comment: @jailaxmik Please refer to the documentation I linked in my response. It shows all of the available operators that you can use in CMake if-statements. The boolean operators are available, but their syntax is `AND` and `OR`.